# Countdown Timer problem

Tags: android, lifecycle

I am using this Android class to implement a countdown: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

I have created an own class My Count:

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
tv_test.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
tv_test.setText("d"+ (millisUntilFinished/(3600000*24))+ " h: "+  (millisUntilFinished/3600000)%24  +" m: " +  (millisUntilFinished/60000) % 60 + " sec: "+   (millisUntilFinished/1000) % 60);

}

}
```

in onStart() of my activity I have this code:

```
MyCount counter = new MyCount(time, 1000);
        counter.start();
```

The problem is now: If I navigate to next activity and come back, the countdowntimer is started again and there run two countdowns.

I can not put it in onCreate() because the time variable can be changed by the user. He changes it on an other activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add a boolean 
 example :

```
booelan counterIsLaunched = false;
boolean timeChanged = false;
```

and in your implementation of the counter add this :

```
@Override
public void onFinish() { tv_test.setText("");
counterIsLaunched = false;
if(timeChanged) start();
}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
tv_test.setText("d"+ (millisUntilFinished/(3600000*24))+ " h: "+  (millisUntilFinished/3600000)%24  +" m: " +  (millisUntilFinished/60000) % 60 + " sec: "+   (millisUntilFinished/1000) % 60);
counterIsLaunched = true;
if(timeChanged) start();
}
```

and in your onStart() try to test the variable

```
if(counter.getCounterIsLaunched() == false ) {
counter.start();
}
```

and when you changed the timer , do something like this :

```
counter.getTimeChanged() = true;
```

hope it helps man :)

Comment: @houcine: good idea! I have one problem left: The user can change the counter implizitly by changing the price of a product. So somehow I have to cancel the timer and schedule it new.

Comment: @tobias : i understand that you want that your counter should be canceled and restarted again if the user changed the time 
 is that what you mean ??

Comment: @houcine: thx for that! I have just added the code above to my project. But if (counter.getCounterIsLaunched() == false) is always true if I get back from an other activity. And yes your last question is what I want at the end :)

Comment: The reason is probably that the MyCount counter object is created again? So it sets  "counterIsLaunched = false " again. I have also tried to add "MyCount counter;" add beginning of my activity, but it causes same behavior

Comment: @tobias : so , if the user change the time , so notify your counter that the time was changed , and if the time was change , u will restart your counter again :) , check my response i've edited it , hope it helps , and hope that's what you want at the end :)

Comment: @hucine: I will test it later on. I think the first problem I have to solve is that the MyCount object is created again and again.

Comment: you can solve it by overridding the method , onsaveInstance(Bundle icicle) ; 
int this method , you put a boolean to true , and in the method onrestoreInstance() , u get that variable boolean , and test , if  the counter is already created , than dont creat it again , take a look about that ;)